# Finding count of objects within a specified time window in SQL (Postgresql DB)

Tags: postgresql

I need to find out all the users who registered for my Postgresql 9.3 backed website in the *24 hour window 2 days ago*. Currently, I'm doing that via running the following queries, and then manually subtracting the difference:

```
select count (*) from auth_user where date_joined > now() - interval'24 hours';
select count (*) from auth_user where date_joined > now() - interval'48 hours';
```

How do I do everything in the same SQL query, including the subtraction? Thanks in advance!

---

If I do `select count (*) from auth_user where date_joined > (now() - interval'48 hours') - (now() - interval'24 hours');`, I get:

> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might
>   need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: The question is misleading without stating your (outdated) version or Postgres. ***Always*** declare your version number.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Sound advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM auth_user
WHERE (date_joined >= NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours') AND
    (date_joined <= NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours')
```

There's also a `BETWEEN` syntax that might feel more natural:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM auth_user
WHERE date_joined BETWEEN
    NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours' AND
    NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours'
```

[Here is the PostgreSQL docs page where BETWEEN is described.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparison.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) filter (where date_joined > now() - interval'24 hours') as last_24_hours,
       count(*) filter (where date_joined > now() - interval'48 hours') as last_48_hours
from auth_user
```

The `filter` clause is available since Postgres 9.4, for older versions you need to use a `case` statement:

```
select count(case when date_joined > now() - interval'24 hours' then 1 end) as last_24_hours,
       count(case when date_joined > now() - interval'48 hours' then 1 end) as last_48_hours
from auth_user
```

Comment: I'm on 9.3, so that's applicable for me. Thanks for the answer! Btw, wouldn't that be `count (case when...` and not `count(when when....` in the second line for pre-9.4?

Comment: @HassanBaig: sorry, copy & paste error. For future questions, always include the Postgres version, especially when using old versions

Comment: Sound advice. So this would give me the two totals in a single command. I actually wanted to get the *difference* of the two totals in the same command, instead of having to calculate that manually.

Comment: As in, if I do `select count (*) from auth_user where date_joined > (now() - interval'48 hours') - (now() - interval'24 hours');`, I get **No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**